# Accessing userData from Listener

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I'm looking to get the `userData` of an element when such element is triggered via a `Listener`.  Basically, get a reference to the "owner" of the `ObservableValue`, in the instance of a `ChangeListener`.

I think this can be better demonstrated via an example :

```java
for(/*something*/) {
    CheckBox newBox = new CheckBox("My Label " + i);
    newBox.setSelected(true);
    newBox.setUserData(object);  //setting this object to access later
    newBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
            //Here I would like to call something to get the UserData 
            //I have just set.  I would need to access "object" set above.
        }
    });
}
```

I have not found a way to do so.  At the moment I could set the `id` of this checkbox and using that id go find the item I need, but this seems to be going against the fact that I can set an object (`userData`) to this node.  Is this not how `userData` is meant to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the keyword `final` :

```java
final CheckBox newBox = new CheckBox("My Label " + i);
```

Then access using :

```java
newBox.getUserData()
```

Comment: Wow.  Much simpler then my solution... I think I need to go back to the books a bit and go back a few steps. `final`, that's all I needed.  Knew it had to be simpler then I thought

Comment: Yes, it is a bit tricky thing about final, and not every book pays appropriate attention to such case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found for this problem (assuming that what I was originally asking not possible).

I ended up creating an implementation of `ChangeListener` that implemented this feature.  This `Listener` looks like this :

```
public class ChangeListenerWithData implements ChangeListener<Boolean> {

    private Object userData;

    public ChangeListenerWithData(Node node) {
        userData = node.getUserData();
    }

    public Object getUserData() {
        return userData;
    }

    public void setUserData(Object userData) {
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
            Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

My code has then become :

```
for(/*something*/) {
    CheckBox newBox = new CheckBox("My Label " + i);
    newBox.setSelected(true);
    newBox.setUserData(object);  //setting this object to access later
    newBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListenerWithData(newBox) {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean old_val, Boolean new_val) {
            //accessing user data
            context.getMyMap().get(this.getUserData().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

I'm always open to better solutions, but in the meantime, I hope this can help someone as well!

Answer (score 0):

I have arrays of `CheckBoxes` and `TextFields`, all using the same listeners, and I use `userData` to tell which is which:

```
cb.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
        final CheckBox source = (CheckBox) event.getSource();
        System.out.println(source.getUserData());
        }
    });
```